# php Как заменить nodeName в библиотеке simple_html_dom

Tags: php

Есть необходимость сменить все теги `<a>...</a>` на `<p>...</p>` в объекте спаренного текста; Использую библиотеку [simple_html_dom](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/api/simple_html_dom_node/outertext/)
пробую через автозамену, как рекомендуют в других вопросах.

```
include_once ("libs/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php");
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$links = $xpath->query('//a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
   $link->outertext = '<p>'.$link->innertext.'</p>';
}

$newContent = $dom->saveHTML();
echo ($newContent);
```

но почему-то не отрабатывает как надо. Может кто подсказать в чем проблема, как поправить ?
В $link храниться следующее значение

```
object(DOMElement)#12616 (18) {
  ["tagName"]=>
  string(1) "a"
  ["schemaTypeInfo"]=>
  NULL
  ["nodeName"]=>
  string(1) "a"
  ["nodeValue"]=>
  string(11) "Element1"
  ["nodeType"]=>
  int(1)
  ["parentNode"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["childNodes"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["firstChild"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["lastChild"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["previousSibling"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["nextSibling"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["attributes"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["ownerDocument"]=>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  ["namespaceURI"]=>
  NULL
  ["prefix"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["localName"]=>
  string(1) "a"
  ["baseURI"]=>
  NULL
  ["textContent"]=>
  string(11) "Element1"
}
object(DOMElement)#12617 (18) {
  ["tagName"]=>

.....
```

Comment: DOMDocument вижу XPath вижу, simple html dom не вижу

Comment: возможно если вы таки будете использовать simple html, то можно будет сделать просто что-то вида `$html = ...load()..; foreach($html->find("a") as $a){ $a->name = "p"}... $htm->save(...)`

Comment: Поправил вопрос... ` $links = $xpath->query('//a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
   $link->name = "p";
} `   не отработало

Comment: то что вы заинклудили simple_html_dom не значит что вы его используете. Используйте вы стандартный DOMDocument. Вы же привели ссылку на документацию, потрудитесь ее почитать - https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/quick-start/

Comment: понял, спасибо. После объявления simple_html_dom удаль добиться правильного результата.... ` $html = str_get_html($newContent);
$replace="a";
foreach($html->find($replace) as $key=>$element){
    $html->find($replace,$key)->outertext="<span>".$element->innertext."</span>";
}`  Жаль что без оптимизации... Но что поделать.

Comment: `$element->outertext = `. не надо там find вызывать еще раз. А чего вы тут еще оптимзировать хотите, и так кратко все вроде

Comment: `$element->tag = 'span'` то не работает? должно вроде.